# java clone() with array

Tags: java, arrays, clone

i am trying this in my copy constructor

```
protected int forca;
 protected Spell []feitico; 
public Picareta(final Picareta rValue)
    {
        super((Ferramenta)rValue);
        this.forca=rValue.forca;
        this.feitico=rValue.feitico.clone();
    }
```

but feitico has the same references instead of cloning the objects in the array

do i really need to clone every element inside the array , or is my clone() for Spell wrong ?

```
public Spell clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
    {
        super.clone();
        Spell temp= new Spell(this);
        return temp;
    }
```

or is this way the best(compact) way to make it ?

```
public Picareta(final Picareta rValue)
    {
        super((Ferramenta)rValue);
        this.forca=rValue.forca;
        this.feitico=new Spell[rValue.feitico.length];
        for (int i=0;i<rValue.feitico.length;i++)
             this.feitico[i]=new Spell(rValue.feitico[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, you would really need to copy every element inside the array.

Comment: then the clone() method is only useful with an array primitives?, because i though the array.clone() were supposed to use my clone() method inside its body or even the copy construtor

Comment: Pretty much, yes.  Assuming `clone()` is useful at all, which...eh.  (Generally speaking, best practice is to make pretty much everything immutable, in which case you never need to copy.)

Comment: now i understand why everybody says its better not to use it, i saves no work as you can use shallow copy for primitives anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `.clone()` on an array object will clone the array.  That does not clone other objects, namely the objects referred to by elements in the array.

What you are asking about is a ["deep copy" or "deep clone"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying#Methods_of_copying).  After creating a new array to hold the new objects, then you need to iterate through the old array and clone each of the objects referred to there:

```
this.feitico = new Spell[rValue.feitico.length];
for (int i = 0; i < this.feitico.length ; i += 1)
    {
    this.feitico[i] = rValue.feitico[i].clone();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`clone` for arrays of reference type is only a shallow copy, so yes you will need to copy every element inside the array.

You already have a copy constructor for `Spell`, so this is not too hard.

Using Java 8, there is a nice way to copy a `Spell[]`:

```
this.feitico = Arrays.stream(rValue.feitico).map(Spell::new).toArray(Spell[]::new);
```

With Java 7 and below, your way cannot be improved.